# ¿Cómo hacer que dos funciones de js se ejecuten?

Tags: javascript, function, submit

La situación que tengo es la siguiente. Tengo dos formularios en páginas diferentes; y cada uno de ellos carga unos registros en otro documento php (uno para cada uno) y he tenido que programar el evento del botón con js ya que el mismo lo tengo fuera del form. La situación es que las dos funciones no se ejecutan; es decir tengo que deshabilitar una para habilitar la otra (Están en un mismo archivo js). ¿Hay alguna posibilidad que funcionen las dos? (No al mismo tiempo ya que cada una hace una cosa diferente. ¡Gracias por su ayuda! (Por cierto. ¿Cómo se manejan los bloques para insertar código? Hay alguien como enojado porque lo inserto aquí en el mensaje; pero es que no sé como hacer ¡Gracias!)

```js
// Submit de formulario Gestión Empleados a ValidarIngresoEmpleado
var myformEmp = document.getElementById("GestionEmp");
document.getElementById("IngresarEmp").addEventListener("click", function ingresarEmp() {
myformEmp.submit();
});

// Función para enviar la información de usuario a la Tabla de Usuarios
var myformUsu = document.getElementById("GestionUsu");
document.getElementById("IngresarUsu").addEventListener("click", function ingresarUsu() {
    myformUsu.submit();
});
```

Comment: je, los bloques de código se hacen seleccionando el código y pulsando el botón `{}` que aparece en la barra de botones del editor. No estoy enojado, pido disculpas si he sido mal interpretado, simplemente informo de lo que veo mal, pero tu hazlo como te apetezca. Piensa que las buenas preguntas tienen mejores respuestas, y **todo** lo que yo te he dicho y te diré es para eso, para mejorar tu pregunta y que ésta sea mejor recibida y recibas mejores respuestas.

Comment: Los snippets son para código JS, HTML y CSS, pero no para PHP, ptyhon, java, etc... en este caso lo puedes dejar en un snippet tranquilamente, pues no hay PHP ni nada parecido.  Aún así, los snippets se usan para demostrar la funcionalidad del código o para mostrar errores del mismo, pues se pueden ejecutar. En este caso tampoco haria falta si no pones el HTML que se corresponde con ese javascript que has puesto.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, no detecto que tu código tenga los problemas que estás comentando, pues en ambos submits usas nombres distintos para todo y no parece que tengan que colisionar entre ellos.  O sea, ¿seguro que no funcionan bien de forma separada de saque?  Es importante que podamos reproducir tu error para ayudarte, por eso quizás necesitemos más información como el formulario que te da problemas con ese javascript que has puesto.

Comment: Hola masterguru. Muchas gracias por tu comprensión y te ofrezco disculpas por tomar a mal una crítica constructiva; procuraré mejorar poco a poco. Ahora bien, encontré otra manera; que hasta ahora me ha funcionado mejor y fue así:   // Submit de form Gestión Usuarios a validaringressarusu.php y query (Funciona)
function registrarusu(){
 document.GestionUsu.submit()
} Nuevamente muchas gracias por tu amable colaboración y trataré de mejorar poco a poco. Feliz noche